# read a powerPoint file using Java or Talend then upload it to SalesForce

Tags: java, salesforce, talend

I need to read a power-point file using Talend or Java then upload it to Salesforce and create it under Documents (standard Object).

Maybe convert it to a binary file?
 
Or there is an option in talend to do it? 
Or creating a  java method under Talend that do the job?
any help in that process will be appreciate it.
I found a way to read the ppt file but without any return in the link
http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ReadPowerPoint

Answer (score 0):

Talend cannot deal with powerPoint file, but you can create a static routine that use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) API for that and invoke it through tJava component, to upload file you can use tFTPPut component.

Comment: Hello @54l3d thank you for your reply but can you explain me what u mean exactly by static routine ? am new on Talend.

Comment: Hello @Neeldz : Routines enable you to write custom code in Java to optimize data processing, improve Job capacity, and to extend Talend Studio features. [Talend help](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Creating+a+user+routine+and+call+it+in+a+Job)